# how to test if array contains item, as is, not some subset of it

Tags: json, key, jq, rename

So it seems that I fell for *contains* function definition, since:

```
yq -n '["hyper"]|contains(["pe"])'
```

'surprisingly' returns true. I don't know what usecase this have, still new to funcitolan world but it's clearly shown in docs as:

```
jq 'contains(["baz", "bar"])'
Input   ["foobar", "foobaz", "blarp"]
Output  true
```

So how to trivially write exact matching, string-is-contained-in-array-contains?

```
yq -n '["hyper"] as $i | $i - ["pe"] != $i'
```

? Or what would be correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` you are using. As you are referring to examples for the `contains` filter in the manual to [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq), I assume you are using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), which is a YAML-wrapper around jq.

jq's `contains` [tests](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#contains%28element%29) if its argument is partially contained in the input. As this is done recursively, it also affects the string items of your array, not only the surrounding array itself. And as `"pe"` is contained in `"hyper"`, it evaluates to `true`.

jq [offers](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any%2Cany%28condition%29%2Cany%28generator%3Bcondition%29) the `any` filter to test if in a given stream at least one item evaluates to `true` for a given filter. For that filter you could use the equals `==` operator which evaluates to `true` for exact matches, and for the stream, if omitted, `any` will [default](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L184) to the items of an input array.

```bash
$ yq -n '["hyper"] | any(. == "pe")'
false
```

```bash
$ yq -n '["hyper"] | any(. == "hyper")'
true
```

---

Just in case, if you do use the other implementation [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), it [offers](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/boolean-operators#any_c-returns-true-if-any-element-in-the-array-is-true-for-the-given-condition.) a similar function called `any_c` (as it is not based on jq and hence has a (sometimes) different syntax):

```bash
$ yq -n '["hyper"] | any_c(. == "pe")'
false
```

```bash
$ yq -n '["hyper"] | any_c(. == "hyper")'
true
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used both yq libraries, but you are correct, I mostly use kislyuk/yq. Sorry for confusion, I wanted to type jq instead, but I because this yq is just wrapper, I did wrong copy-paste without double checking. I'm accepting this answer since it contains more information for 2 different yq specific libraries (and any is easier for me to  read)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a jq-like implementation, you'd use [`IN`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) (capitalized)

```bash
$ jq -n --arg elem "pe"    '["hyper"] as $list | $elem | IN($list[])'
false

$ jq -n --arg elem "hyper" '["hyper"] as $list | $elem | IN($list[])'
true
```

The argument to `IN()` is a *stream* of elements, not an array.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked the jq documentation, and this operation is not mentioned there. I experiment with it, thanks for teaching me new function. Question: where I can find all available functions? Maybe there are more of them I'd like to know.

Comment: "I checked the jq documentation, and this operation is not mentioned there" -- did you follow the link I put in my answer?

Comment: uff, sorry. Wrong expectation. I expected it listed among whole operations, didn't read the sql-like operations paragraph as my brain evaluated what it saw as broken anchor. Sorry once more.